# How to set a button in on and off state ( on and off image)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-listview

I am new to android and working with the following code, I am trying to set a default image button which when clicked switched to the on state till pressed again or tapped anywhere else on the screen such that the popup associated with the on state goes away.
Here's the code:
java code:

```
private void setOnclickListeners(View view){
        ImageButton button = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

I want to connect this code to the following so on and off states are triggered:

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/menu_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/menu_btn" />
```

Here's the menu_btn code for xml class :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/menu_on"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/menu_on" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_off" />  
</selector>
```

Any clue how to go about it? Ant help appreciated. Thanks!justin

Comment: Wouldn't [toggleButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html) be a better choice to use?

Comment: no clue? can you please edit my code for the toggle button and show how it works?Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check [`ToggleButton`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html) (or any sub-class of [`Checkable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Checkable.html)) for your implementation and then setting its state to something like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/menu_off"/>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/menu_on" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_off" />  
</selector>
```

Then on your Java code, get an instance of your `ToggleButton` (or `Checkable`) and update the `setChecked`-method accordingly to your actions.